# Can't add tab page from user control with events

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events, tabcontrol

Ok, I have 2 class who can add a tab page to the tabcontrol

- Communication : Class, Using event
- GeneralChat : UserControl, Double clicking on the name in the listbox

The way I do it go like this

The following function are from `GeneralChat`

Handle when double click to create a new tab page

```
Private Sub ListConnecte_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListConnecte.MouseDoubleClick
    addTab(ListConnecte.SelectedItems(0)) 'I've simplified the function, but it's not passing an empty value
End Sub
```

Create the TabPAge

```
Private Sub addTab(sUser As String)
    Dim tp As New TabPage(sUser)
    Dim pc As New PrivateChat(Me, weComs, sUser)

    pc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    tp.Controls.Add(pc)

    If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        Me.Invoke(New AddTabDelegate(AddressOf MainForm.addTab), tp)
    Else
        MainForm.addTab(tp)
    End If

    listChat.Add(sUser, tp)
End Sub
```

it then go in the mainform where the variable `TabControlChat` has been created and add it to the `TabControlChat.TabPages`

So my problem is, when I double click , everything work fine, but when I call it this way

```
Private Sub ReceivedString_weComs(Sender As Object, e As WithParamReceivedString) Handles weComs.ReceivedString
    Select Case e.Identifier
        Case Communication.enumTags.PrivateChat
            Dim sNom() As String = e.ReceivedString.Split(New String() {"#*#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            If (Not listChat.ContainsKey(sNom(0))) Then
                addTab(sNom(0))
            Else
                RaiseEvent PrivateChatString(Me, New ReceivedStringEventArgs(e.ReceivedString))
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

so this function go to the same path the precedent call did, but one add the tabcontrol and from Communication class it dont

I've really tried alot, ask me more question about debugging if I've not been clear enought, hope you can help :S

Comment: Your usage of MainForm in the Invoke call is the problem.  MainForm is a type, it is not an object.  Convenient in VB.NET but absolutely lethal in code that runs on a worker thread.  Now "MainForm" becomes an instance of *another* MainForm object.  One that's owned by the worker thread and not visible because its Show() method was never called.  You *must* use a proper reference to the MainForm object that the user is looking at.  Like Me.

Answer (score 0):

In the second piece of code, You are actually refering to an object of The MainForm, (which is actually invisible, until you call the .show method). You must use the orginal MainForm, which is already visible to the user.